# Hidden input field missing from DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a problem embarrassing problem with hidden field not being part of DOM; at least I cannot find it using JavaScript.  Field has "id" and "name" attributes, it is in the form, has a value and can be seen when looking at the view source in browser. So, I attach a click handler to a button, which looks for a hidden field using either document.getElementById or using jquery selectors (any combination of the selectors, by Id, by class name etc) and it is not part of DOM. How is this possible, or is it even possible? What could be a cause if this?

Edit:
Markup is huge, so I did not want to paste it in here. My question was basically, is it possible for hidden field to be missing from DOM. Why are people down-voting this? Is it not  a valid question?

Comment: Please share the markup. Broken markup could certainly be one cause.

Comment: Something misspelled?  Typo?  Part of a tag missing?  Improper syntax?  Does it pass [validation](http://validator.w3.org/)?  All just guesses without seeing any of your actual code.

Comment: Markup and Javascript will definitely help. Anything else we can give you is just conjecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the field has been removed, the browsers viewsource doesn't care about changes of the DOM(It is just the response he gets from the server).
Use e.g. firebugs HTML-tab to inspect the current DOM.

Comment: Aha, you guessed it right, something is removing the hidden field, I just confirmed it, one page has it, and the other does not.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible if your javascript code is running as is, ie not inside a DOM ready event, but as in the normal flow of the document. If your javascript code is placed above the html that declares this hidden field, then the browser will execute the javascript before it got the chance to create the elemeent. You are able to see it in view source because by that time the browser has rendered everything.

So my blind guess is that your js code in NOT inside a DOM ready event. I could very well be wrong. Please post the least possible html markup and css and javascript that will reproduce this problem. You may use [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) to share the code with us ...